# How to write the query equivalent to "WHERE a0 OR a1 OR a2 ..." clause in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

In django, I want to use a little complex query for improving performance.
What I want to do is exactly the following.

```
query = Q()  # EDITED: incorrect "None" replace to "Q()"

# we don't know conditions length until the program runs.
for x, y in conditions:
    query |= Q(x=x, y=y)
coordinates = Coordinate.objects.filter(query)

for x, y in conditions:
    c = coordinates.get(x=x, y=y)
    print(c)  # execute related to "c"
```

It works well.
However, I doubt this is the best. I think probably Django has more useful and effective queries.
Does anyone know the way?

Comment: I think your first variant is the way to go about things.

Comment: If we are talking efficiency, it is as efficient as it gets, as the evaluation happens lazily at render.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Oh... it's a mistake. actually I did not try to run yet. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing is, well, I'm not sure `None |= Q(x-x,y=y)` will work. I think you need to initialize with `Q()`, but then again the latest Django version I've worked with is 1.6 so dunno if it changed. (Then again,I'd probably write it as something like, oh, `import operator; import functools; functools.reduce(operator.or_,[Q(x=x,y=y) for x,y in conditions], Q())`, because I'm evil :P

Answer (score 2):

In your case, every call of the `print` function is doing a database query!

Query sets delay execution until the time they're run. This link explains how:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Execute your query first, outside the for loop. Then iterate over the results inside the for loop and print them.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by the following way.

```
d = dict(((cd.x, cd.y), cd) for cd in coordinates.all())

for x, y in conditions:
    c = d[(x, y)]
    print(c)
```